# iOS Vision framework with only ARKit import

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, arkit, apple-vision

I hope it's not a silly question, but why this iOS Swift code compiles successfully?

```swift
import UIKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let sequenceHandler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

I expect that `VNSequenceRequestHandler` would not be found since `Vision` is not imported.
Does `ARKit` automatically imports `Vision` framework? Because if I right click on `import ARKit` and click "Jump to definition", in Xcode I see this
[image: Situation when I jumped to ARKit definition from Xcode]

I don't know where `SwiftUI` come from (this project use `UIKit`) and where `Vision` come from.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### That's because ARKit is an umbrella framework

ARKit has access to all the classes of such important frameworks as UIKit, AVFoundation, SceneKit, SpriteKit, Vision, CoreGraphics, etc. When I develop AR app I import just ARKit module. Consider, there's no access to SwiftUI through ARKit at the moment.

There is some kind of logic in it. SceneKit is needed for importing of models and rendering, CoreMotion and AVFoundation are the basis on which ARSession is built. And finally, how can we do without ML algorithms when recognizing images or classifying objects? For this, all the supporting frameworks are integrated into ARKit.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that frameworks dependencies could be used only by the framework itself, not the whole app in such a transparent way. Thank you again :)