# What's the difference between ARKit and RealityKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

From **developer.apple.com**, it is described as follows,

> ARKit: Integrate iOS device camera and motion features to produce augmented reality experiences in your app or game.

and

> RealityKit: Simulate and render 3D content for use in your augmented reality apps.

As I understand, ARKit is AR SDK acts on object detection and tracking, RealityKit is rendering module.

In my project, I imported only **RealityKit** framework into Xcode for making the AR Application. Plus, I used **Reality Composer** for creating the experience attached to the image. Finally, my AR application can work completely.

However, I have 2 questions:

1. Is RealityKit an AR SDK?
2. Which part is responsible for detecting and tracking the image anchor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### RealityKit vs ARKit

The RealityKit's [ARSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593960/whats-the-difference-between-aranchor-and-anchorentity/57630001#57630001) is based on the ARKit's AR session, but has its own `add-ons` that allow you to automate the tracking of several anchors' types. However, the difference between two is that [RealityKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505755/realitykit-vs-scenekit-vs-metal-high-quality-rendering/60513052#60513052) has engines for rendering, physics and animation. And do not forget that ARKit is [umbrella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68380176/ios-vision-framework-with-only-arkit-import/68382729#68382729) containing SceneKit and SpriteKit.

Comment: Does the model entity represent the virtual objects on the anchor?

Comment: What do you mean by saying this? Please decipher. (model entity is your 3d model)

Comment: OK, I got it. (I meant **Does the model entity represent the 3d model?**)

Answer (score 2):

[RealityKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/) is Apple’s 3D framework integrating virtual objects into the real world using the augmented reality framework [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit) which helps to find and track real-world surfaces and objects.
All of this can be kick-started using [Reality Composer Pro](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/designing-realitykit-content-with-reality-composer-pro) as an easy visual drag-and-drop way (think of Interface Builder for iOS/macOS apps) to create a scene before moving to code with RealityKit.